# Loop space generalization

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Let $X$ be a based connected space. The space of based continuous morphisms $Top_{\ast}(S^1,X)$ 
is the space of loops $\Omega X$. Since $S^1$ is homotopy equivalent to the Eilenberg-Mac Lane Space $K(\mathbf{Z},1)$ I was wandering if there is any "geometric interpretation" of the space of based continuous morphisms $Top_{\ast}(\mathbf{C}P^{\infty},X)$.  $\mathbf{C}P^{\infty}$ can be identified with the Eilenberg-Mac Lane Space $K(\mathbf{Z},2)$
More generally, what would be the "geometric interpretation" of the space of based continuous morphisms $Top_{\ast}(K(\mathbf{Z},n),X)$.

Comment: $S^1$ has two interesting kinds of extra structure as an object of the homotopy category of based spaces: first, it's a cogroup object, but second, it's a group object. The first kind of extra structure is the one related to loop spaces, while the second kind of extra structure is the one related to its description as $B \mathbb{Z}$. The Eilenberg-MacLane spaces $B^n \mathbb{Z}, n \ge 2$, on the other hand, are only group objects, and have no cogroup structure (since their cohomology has interesting cup products).

Comment: There is an homotopy theoretic interpretation (I don't know if I can call it geometric) for maps from $CP^{\infty} \to X$ when $X = BY$ for an $A_{\infty}$ H-space $Y$. They are precisely the maps from $S^1 \to Y$ which are $A_{\infty}$ maps. (I apologies for recklessly putting something wrong as answer and convey my thanks to Dylan Wilson for pointing it out.)

Comment: @Prasit Thanks, I think your argument is nice. I think you need to add that Y is group-like. I think I see how to think about the interpretation of $Top_{\ast}(K(\mathbf{Z},n),X) $ using $E_{n}$ operads.

Comment: I know Dylan pointed out group-like, but I am not sure if we actually need the condition 'group-like'.

Answer (score 2):

[Edited after the comment below]
Well, I don't know exactly what you mean by "geometric interpretation", but 
for topological group $G$ the unpointed mapping spaces $Map(BG,X)$ are examples of [homotopy fixed points.](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/homotopy+fixed+point) and the pointed mapping spaces $Map_*(BG,X)$ fits in the fibration
$$Map_*(BG,X) \rightarrow Map(BG,X) \rightarrow X$$ where the last map is
the evaluation map.

Now, $$Map(BG,X)\cong Map^G(EG,X)$$ where we provide $X$ with trivial action,
and this latter is nothing but the homotopy fixed points of $X$ with trivial $G$-action.

If $G$-action on $X$ is trivial, $X$ is just the fixed point set, so one can consider $Map_*(BG,X)$ as the space that measures the difference between the genuine fixed point set and the homotopy fixed point set.

As one can construct a model for $K(A,n-1)$ that has a structure of a topological group, you can take $G=K(A,n-1)$ in the above.

Comment: Are you sure about your definition of homotopy fixed points. Your are using the pointed maps.

Comment: @Max you are right, I corrected the answer.